# Will plants continue to produce crops in their second season if not removed?

Tags: stardew-valley

When the season ends, the now out-of-season crop plants become dormant (or dead?) and stop producing crops, but don't disappear. If I let the plants stay around until the next time their season comes, will they keep producing crops or are they essentially dead and useless forever?

Comment: @Kyralessa Well, it seems to work with many plants in real life, so I'm not sure why that's an unreasonable thought.

Comment: @Chippies Aside from the fruit trees, which do survive over winter, there aren't many crops in the game that are normally planted as perennials on farms. Grapes are the only thing that comes to mind. Plants like tomatoes and strawberries are technically perennials, but tomatoes can't survive the winter outside their native tropical growing zones, and strawberries are normally replanted each year because their yield drops after the first.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Winter will remove crops, so they won't survive to a second season.

Answer (score 2):

I can see that people say that ALL crops will wither (and all other 'new' seasons) and die at winter. This is not the case at me. 5 of my cranberries managed to survive (Don't ask me how) and they are still producing. All other crops, including other cranberries died though.

Comment: I noticed that with one of my Corn crops, out of like 50, though i chopped it down right away because i did not care and it was winter. Unsure if this is a bug or it is just chance.